# what are these little plant stuff growing in the pot of my house tree?

Tags: trees, indoors

[image][image]

what are these little plants growing in the soil of my house plant?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like sun flower seedlings. Do you have a perrot or caged bird next to the plant that throws seeds into the pot?

Comment: Ah, brilliant suggestion @benn! But why did the seedlings all come up at the same time?

Comment: The only problem with that suggestion is it would be hard not to notice 20 sunflower seeds in the pot before they germinated, unless the parrot was clever enough to bury them :)

Comment: Maybe @haley can explain more about the situation there? Is bird seeds a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going with sunflower or pumpkin seedlings. Seeing the adult leaves in a few weeks would be more telling.